# Why StreamBuilder does not update screen data

Tags: flutter

Please help me to understand, why screens are not rebuilded with updated data.

Here is the topmost widget, where i wrap MaterialApp with StreamBuilder:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bloc = BlocSingleton();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: bloc.dataStream,
      initialData: 'initial data',
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('Stream updated with snapshot.data: ${snapshot.data}');
        return MaterialApp(
          routes: {
            '/': (context) {
              print('Home route activated with: ${snapshot.data}');
              return Home(data: snapshot.data);
            },
            '/my_screen': (context) {
              print('MyScreen route activated with: ${snapshot.data}');
              return MyScreen(data: snapshot.data);
            },
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is `Home` screen, where i have a button to go to `MyScreen`:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;

  Home({this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Home builded');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('to my_screen'),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/my_screen');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('$data'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is `MyScreen` screen with the button to push updated data to stream:

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bloc = BlocSingleton();
  final String data;

  MyScreen({this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MyScreen builded');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyScreen'),
        actions: [
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('update stream'),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {
              bloc.dataSink.add('--- updated data ---');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('$data'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So from `Home` screen i press the button and go to `MyScreen`.
Console output is:

```
I/flutter (26700): Stream updated with snapshot.data: initial data
I/flutter (26700): Home route activated with: initial data
I/flutter (26700): Home builded
I/flutter (26700): MyScreen route activated with: initial data
I/flutter (26700): MyScreen builded
```

Then i press the button to update stream and got output in console:

```
I/flutter (26700): Stream updated with snapshot.data: --- updated data ---
I/flutter (26700): Home route activated with: initial data
I/flutter (26700): Home builded
I/flutter (26700): MyScreen route activated with: initial data
I/flutter (26700): MyScreen builded
```

So as you can see, screens rebuilded with previous data: "initial data", but not with updated data: "--- updated data ---".

I know that screens can be StatefulWidget-s and when screen popped from stack, we can return value to previous screen and call `setState` there to rebuild it. But it feels not the best approach.

Comment: It resets to ```Home``` screen, but with data updated. So now, with KEY, as i understand, every time StreamBuilder emits a new data MaterialApp rebuilded, Navigator stack got cleared and we came to the default route "/" (Home screen). What i can do, if i do not want to clear the navigator stack.

Comment: tried `onGenerateRoute: ...`?

Comment: @pskink Can you add a little detail please?

Comment: ok, never mind, it does not work either... ;-(

Comment: I feel very dumb about all this flutter stuff. I have a large tree-like structure and each depth level of this structure i want to be on its own screen. I want to come to leaf trough all levels(screens) and change some data. After that StreamBuilder emits new structure and updates all screens on stack. So when i press back button on each screen on way up i see updated data. But that not work :(

Comment: if I were you I would try Navigator v2 stuff (MaterialApp.router) - it is much more flexible